# How to upload file to AWS server using sftp from laravel controller?

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, sftp

I am using

> composer require phpseclib/phpseclib

```
use phpseclib\Net\SFTP;

$sftp = new SFTP('www.example.com');

if (!$sftp->login('username', 'password')) {
    throw new Exception('Login failed');
}
```

The error caused when run into this line

> $sftp = new SFTP('www.example.com');

I tried at local with this method, it runs fine.
When i use it in my server then it returns a blank page with internal error 500.

My server host: 52.xxx.xxx.xxx, file to be uploaded to host: testing.pb.com

Any solution to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you provide the complete error log/stack trace of the 500 error? It could hold the answer on why the connection is not working!

Comment: do you have require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php' before the use statement?

Comment: Why don't you add a disk in filesystem.php with the sftp connection? https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem search for SFTP Driver Configuration

Comment: @FMK I cannot see the error log. Response show no data available.

Comment: @PedroFaria99 yes.

Comment: @SérgioReis need to install any package for using it?

Comment: Yes, it has the dependency in `Driver Prerequisites` install this `composer install league/flysystem-sftp ~1.0`